# If two bodies move constantly but with different speed, do they move with acceleration relative to each other?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, velocity, speed

If two bodies move constantly but with different speed, do they move with acceleration relative to each other?

Comment: When you say constantly do you mean that both bodies have a constant velocity?

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there would be no acceleration.

If we have $x_1 = v_1 t + x_{1,0}$ and $x_2 = v_2 t + x_{2,0}$, then the distance between them is described by $x_2 - x_1 = (v_2 - v_1) t + x_{2,0} - x_{1,0}$. As you can see, this distance grows with constant speed $v_2 - v_1$ and there isn't relative acceleration.

Comment: By another words, in the frame of one of them, the distance between them changes constantly, right?

Comment: The difference in velocity between the two objects is constant, but there is no acceleration between the two objects.